# ERROR: tensorflow 1.13.0rc2 has requirement tensorboard<1.13.0,>=1.12.0, but you'll have tensorboard 1.14.0 which is incompatible

Tags: tensorflow, installation, windows-10

I was trying to install `tensorflow gpu` on Windows 10, but I encountered following error messages:

```
ERROR: tensorflow 1.13.0rc2 has requirement tensorboard<1.13.0,>=1.12.0, but you'll have tensorboard 1.14.0 which is incompatible.
ERROR: tensorflow 1.13.0rc2 has requirement tensorflow-estimator<1.14.0rc0,>=1.13.0rc0, but you'll have tensorflow-estimator 1.14.0 which is incompatible.
Installing collected packages: google-pasta, wrapt, tensorflow-estimator, tensorflow-gpu
  Found existing installation: wrapt 1.10.11
ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'wrapt'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.
```

What is the problem and how can I fix it?